# cleveref is not using the selected language

Tags: cleveref, polyglossia

Problem using `polyglossia` and `cleveref` (vanilla install). It is not using the selected language.

Example document, where it's used only package's supported languages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Test1}\label{sec:test1}
Blablabla \Cref{sec:test1}.
\selectlanguage{english}
\section{Test2}\label{sec:test2}
Blablabla \Cref{sec:test2}.
\end{document}
```

The result is presented below. Note that before the second section, we have selected `english` as the current language, but it appears `Abschnitt` instead.

[image]

The following error also appears when using *portuguese* as main language (whether using `variant=brazilian` or not):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...ame extras\cref@language
                                                  \endcsname }\@ifundefined ...
```

This problem is caused because `cleveref` defines the language `brazilian` instead of `portuguese`.

Comment: it helps to read the documentation: "Cleveref recognises these commands, so you should not pass language options to cleveref when using polyglossia."

Comment: is it new? 'cos I guess it did work previously... (on Overleaf version for example, it does)

Comment: No idea, I neither use polyglossia nor cleveref much. I only checked the documentation.

Comment: IMHO best would be to participate to add the missing support of another language to `cleveref`. See section 14.3 of the manual for more information.

Comment: The OP's german/english code works as intended for me in TL 2021 but `\Cref` does not recognise the change in language in TL 2022. I cannot see how to apply the currently marked duplicate to the OP's current example.  That said, I suspect [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665219/106162) is a suitable duplicate candidate instead.

Comment: @LEo does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665219/106162) resolve or help with your current question?  If I add `\providecommand\german@loaded{}` and `\providecommand\english@loaded{}` inside `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` your current MWE appears to compile as intended.

Comment: @DaiBowen it did work!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @DaiBowem, this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665219/106162) says that "`\cref@addlanguagedefs` is currently broken if you use `polyglossia`", the command to check if a a language has been loaded no longer exists. The fix is to provid those missing commands by adding:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\german@loaded{}
\providecommand\english@loaded{}
\makeatother
```

and the patched example will be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\german@loaded{}
\providecommand\english@loaded{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test1}\label{sec:test1}
Blablabla \Cref{sec:test1}.
\selectlanguage{english}
\section{Test2}\label{sec:test2}
Blablabla \Cref{sec:test2}.
\end{document}
```

giving the expected result

[image]