# How to make cleveref references use a language-sensitive connective between multiple references, when the document's language is Hebrew?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, polyglossia, hebrew, right-to-left

The following question builds on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665040/21685).

---

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[english]{cleveref}
\appto{\captionshebrew}{%
   \crefname{theorem}{thm}{thms}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{t1}
This is the first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{t2}
This is the second theorem.
\end{theorem}

Here are references to~\cref{t1,t2}.

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> > cd ~
> > xelatex test
> > xelatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[![Referencing multiple labels][1]][1]

(Note that Hebrew is a right-to-left language.)

The word `and` between the references to the two theorems was injected automatically by `cleverer`. However, this connective is an English word, and therefore is not the correct word in the present context; it should have been the Hebrew counterpart `וגם`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: copy from cleverref.sty a language definition (e.g. everything from `\DeclareOption{italian}{%` to the closing brace) in your preamble. This are around 200 lines. Then replace everything in a suitable way to define the hebrew language.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've followed your suggestion, but it didn't work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[english]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ AA }
\newcommand\crefrangepreconjunction{ BB }
\newcommand\crefrangepostconjunction{ CC }
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ DD }
\newcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{ EE }
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ FF }
\newcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction}{ GG }
\newcommand{\crefmiddlegroupconjunction}{ HH }
\newcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ II }

\crefname{definition}{DEFINITION}{DEFINITIONS}
\crefname{theorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}
\crefname{claim}{CLAIM}{CLAIMS}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{d2}
This is another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{d3}
This is yet another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{claim}\label{c}
This is a theorem.
\end{claim}

Here is a reference to~\cref{d1,d2,d3,t,c} based upon~\cref{d1,d2,t}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Cleveref workout]

**Notes**

1. I don't know what the commands `\crefmiddleconjunction` and `\creflastconjunction` do, and would appreciate if someone tells me, so I can revise the above code and make it complete.
2. The solution above is good only for a monolingual document in which the main, and essentially only, language is Hebrew. I don't know how to modify it for bilingual documents in which some parts have Hebrew as the main language, whereas other parts have English as the main language.

Comment: naturally you should remove the `\DeclareOption{hebrew}{`  (and the closing brace). That is for the package. You only need the content.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I see. What about the `\usepackage[hebrew]{cleveref}` line? should the option be `hebrew`, `english`, or none? And should the `\usepackage` line precede or succede the `\DeclareOption` block, or does it not matter? And what about the line `\def\cref@language{hebrew}` -- should I keep it, or delete it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've removed the `\DeclareOption{hebrew}{` (and the closing brace), as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please do not post edits as answers to your questions. Instead, use the Edit link and edit your question. You can insert a horizontal line using `---` as separator.

Comment: Read the error message and make some educated guesses.

Answer (score 5):

If you look into the `cleveref` code you can see that language support consist of two parts: At first a language option is defined, followed by a `\cref@addlanguagedefs` command which repeats everything. The second part is meant for multilingual documents.

But `\cref@addlanguagedefs` is currently broken if you use `polyglossia`: To test if a language has been loaded it uses an internal `polyglossia` command that no longer exists, so to make use of it you have to provide the missing commands for every language:

Move also the newtheorem declaration behind cleveref.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[english]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}

\makeatletter
%work around cleveref bug:
\providecommand\hebrew@loaded{}
\providecommand\english@loaded{}

\cref@addlanguagedefs{hebrew}
 {%
  \renewcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ AA }%
  \renewcommand\crefrangepreconjunction{ BB }%
  \renewcommand\crefrangepostconjunction{ CC }%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ DD }%
  \renewcommand{\crefmiddleconjunction}{ EE }%
  \renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ FF }%
  \renewcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction}{ GG }%
  \renewcommand{\crefmiddlegroupconjunction}{ HH }%
  \renewcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ II }%
  \crefname{definition}{DEFINITION}{DEFINITIONS}%
  \crefname{theorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}%
  \crefname{claim}{CLAIM}{CLAIMS}%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{d2}
This is another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{d3}
This is yet another definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{claim}\label{c}
This is a theorem.
\end{claim}

Here is a reference to~\cref{d1,d2,d3,t,c} based upon~\cref{d1,d2,t}.

\selectlanguage{english}
Here is a reference to~\cref{d1,d2,d3,t,c} based upon~\cref{d1,d2,t}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I cannot use this solution, because it fails when `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem` is replaced by `thmtools`'s `\declaretheorem`. I need to use the `thmtools` package in order to work around a quirk (bug?) of the `cleveref` package, as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665180/21685).

Comment: that is not a bug. See 6 Overriding the Cross-Reference Type in the cleveref documentation how to change the type of a label.

Comment: Thank you, but the tools described in chapter 6 of the `cleveref` package are unable to solve the issue described in my other post. Chapter 6 describes how to alias a counter to a different name. This is helpful, as stated in chapter 6, "if you want multiple counters to use the same cross-reference format". But my case is the reverse: I want the same counter to use multiple cross-reference formats, since all the theorem environments I defined use the same counter, namely `definition`, in order for their numbering to be unified and continuous.

Comment: The chapter also mention the optional argument of label.

Comment: Technically you're correct, but this trick was designed for a use-case of an exceptional circumstance, it is not suitable as a general solution to the use case described in my other post. To quote the `cleveref` manual's sentence introducing the optional argument to `\label`: "*Occasionally*, you may want to override the cross-reference type for *one particular* label, *one-of*" (my emphases). If I have to indicate for each label what name `cleveref` should use to reference it, what's the point of using the `cleveref` package?

Comment: yes, and it continues with *If you need to do this frequently, it can become tedious specifying the label explicitly each time* and then recommends `aliascnt`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/2388 for an implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still, it's much simpler and more transparent/self-documenting to implement a solution using the `thmtools` package, and at any rate I feel that it should be possible to use `cleveref` and `thmtools` simultaneously in a bilingual document, just as it is possible to use them simultaneously in a monolingual English document.

Comment: If I use `babel`+`lualatex` all I need to change is delete the two `\providecommand` lines, right?