# cleveref refers to a theorem as a definition when theorems and definitions share a counter

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, cleveref

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}\label{d}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

Here is a reference to~\cref{t}.
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> > cd ~
> > pdflatex test
> > pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: The reference to the theorem displays as a reference to a definition.]

Notice that the reference to the theorem is displayed as a reference to a definition.

How can I get `\cref` to distinguish between the theorem and the definition, while maintaining a continuous, unified numbering schema for theorems definitions?

Comment: For this MWE to work properly, all you need to do is load the `cleveref` package *before* the `\newtheorem` directives are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem, numberlike=definition]{theorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefname{definition}{Definition}{Definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

Here is a reference to~\cref{t} based upon \cref{d}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The two `\crefname` lines are redundant. Would you please delete them so your code be minimal, for future reference?

Comment: @EvanAad: The two `\crefname` lines are *not* redundant, since they cause the references to appear with capitalized T and D; without them, those initial letters would be lower-case.

Comment: According to the `cleveref` manual, if you prefer to capitalize all cross-reference names, you can pass the `capitalize` option to the `cleveref` package. However, this preference is irrelevant to my original question, and therefore its implementation in your answer, by whatever means, is redundant.

Comment: It's ***much*** better to declare the theorems *after* loading the packages.

Comment: @egreg: because ??