# How to implement cleveref`s aliascnt method for theorem-like environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, counters, cleveref, alias

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258853/21685) demonstrates how to use the `aliascnt` method to create an `ineq` environment which shares a counter with the `equation` environment, but which `cleveref` can nevertheless recognize as a different environment than `equation`.

The code which the answer uses to define the `ineq` environment is copied from the code used in `latex.ltx` to define the `equation` environment. Consequently, the answer is specific to situations in which it is desirable to define `equation`-like environments.

However, how can the `aliascnt` method be used when the new environment to be defined is similar to `theorem` rather than to `equation`, as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665175/21685)?

Comment: Please provide a few more details about "the new environment to be defined similar to `theorem`". E.g., does this new environment have a name? And, would this "new environment" share a counter with the `theorem` environment? For that matter, how is the `theorem` environment defined in the first place? E.g., with the help of the `amsthm` or `ntheorem` package? (The more details you can provide, the more specific and more pertinent answers are likely to be too.)

Comment: @Mico The MWE is the one described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665175/21685), to which I also refer in my post above. If you want, I can copy and paste it into my current post. The MWE does not use `ntheorem`.

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that's wrong about the MWE in [the posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/665175/5001) referenced by the OP is that the `cleveref` package is loaded too late, i.e., only *after* the `\newtheorem` directives are executed. If the `\usepackage{cleveref}` is placed after `\usepackage{amsthm}` and *before* `\newtheorem`, the `\cref` command produces the expected, i.e., correct, output.

FWIW, the need to load the `cleveref` package before the `\newtheorem` commands are executed if the `amsthm` (or `ntheorem`) package is loaded is mentioned several times in the user guide of the `cleveref` package. E.g., in section 14.1, "Non-bugs", the second bullet point states [highlighting added]:

[image]

Finally, I see no need to incur the hassles of the `aliascnt` method -- at least not for the use case at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,cleveref}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}\label{d}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

Here is a cross-reference to~\cref{t}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be a reason why I recommend to load the needed packages and *then* do settings. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you. You wrote: "the need to load the cleveref package before the \newtheorem commands are executed is discussed in section 8.1.3 the user guide of the cleveref package." I don't see any hint of this in section 8.1.3 of the user guide. At the same time, section 13 starts with the admonition: "the \usepackage{cleveref}
line should usually be the last \usepackage command in your document’s preamble."

Comment: I don't know whether to accept your answer. On the one hand, you didn't answer the question I asked, namely about the `aliascnt` method. On the other hand, you answered the question I was *actually* interested in, and the impetus for the current question.

Comment: @EvanAad - I've edited the answer to provide a clearer reference in the user guide to the need to load `cleveref` *before` running `\newtheorem`.